# Upload in background on Flutter

Tags: flutter

What’s the best way to upload data in the background, but don’t cancel this upload when the user switches screens? I would also like to show Snackbar when the upload finishes (even if I'm on a different screen already).

On Android, I’ve been using  Service + BroadcastReceiver or WorkManager. I Can’t find the way of doing it in Flutter.

Answer (score 4):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader
This plugin is based on `WorkManager` in `Android` and `NSURLSessionUploadTask` in `iOS` to run upload task in background mode.

Create new upload task:

```
final uploader = FlutterUploader();

final taskId = await uploader.enqueue(
  url: "your upload link", //required: url to upload to
  files: [FileItem(filename: filename, savedDir: savedDir, fieldname:"file")], // required: list of files that you want to upload
  method: UploadMethod.POST, // HTTP method  (POST or PUT or PATCH)
  headers: {"apikey": "api_123456", "userkey": "userkey_123456"},
  data: {"name": "john"}, // any data you want to send in upload request
  showNotification: false, // send local notification (android only) for upload status
  tag: "upload 1"); // unique tag for upload task
);
```

Listen for upload progress

```
final subscription = uploader.progress.listen((progress) {
  //... code to handle progress
});
```

For `Snackbar` , you can use `ScaffoldMessenger` to make `Snackbar` `persist across routes` https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger

The `ScaffoldMessenger` now handles `SnackBars` in order to `persist across routes` and always be displayed on the current Scaffold. By default, a root ScaffoldMessenger is included in the `MaterialApp`
The `ScaffoldMessenger` creates a scope in which all descendant `Scaffolds` register to receive SnackBars, which is how they persist across these transitions. When using the root `ScaffoldMessenger` provided by the `MaterialApp`
code snippet

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: const Text('snack'),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'ACTION',
          onPressed: () { },
        ),
      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

---

You can use this dart package [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)